# Is it better to have "become" in "make somebody (become) more mature"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it better to have "become" in "make somebody (become) more mature"?
For example,

> The mathematical courses have made me (become) more mathematically mature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Become* is superfluous. The construction *make X ADJ* is equivalent to *cause X to become ADJ*, so the notion of *become* is already present in the idiom.

> John made Susan happy.
>   The mathematics<sup>†</sup> courses have made me more mathematically mature.

This is sometimes, but not always, the case with *make X NOUN*.

> Washington made Lafayette a general = Washington caused Lafayette to become a general, *and*
>   The mathematics courses made me a mathematician = The mathematics courses caused me to become a mathematician, *but*
>   John made Susan a cake = John made a cake **for** Susan.

If you want to say that John caused Susan to become a cake—presumably John is a sorcerer of some sort?—you must say

> John made Susan **into** a cake.

ADDED:
The construction with a verb phrase, *make X VP*, has a slightly different sense: not merely *cause X to [do such-and-such]* but ***required*** or **compelled** X to [do such-and-such]:

> John made Susan bake a cake = John compelled Susan to bake a cake.
>   The mathematics courses made me think more deeply about numbers = The mathematics courses required me to think more deeply.
>   The Devil made me do it! = The Devil compelled me to do it.

If you want to express to *cause X to [do such-and-such]*, you may use *cause X to VP* or you may say *have X VP*:

> John had Susan bake a cake.
>   The mathematics courses caused me to think more deeply about numbers. ...This doesn't suit very well with *have*, because *have* implies deliberate agency. You might say "The mathematics professor had me read Euler's *Vollständige Anleitung zur Algebra*."

---

<sup>†</sup> Note that we say *mathematics* course, not *mathematical course*. *Mathematics* is the subject of study.

Comment: I see a slight distinction between *made me*, as in *as a result of* and *made me become* as in *required me to be*  So the class made me a better mathematician, but the her teaching methods made me become a more methodical thinker.  And using *become* emphasizes the transformation process rather than just the result.

Comment: @Jim Good point. I have added a section on the construction with VP.